# Access properties of inheriting class

Tags: c#, list, inheritance

I have a class as follows:

```
class Object
{
   ...
   Method();
}
```

And a number of classes which inherit it:

```
class ObjectVariant1 : Object
{
   ...
   Method1();
}

class ObjectVariant2 : Object
{
   ...
   Method2();
}
```

I have a list, into which all objects are put:

```
List<Object> objectList = new List<Object>();
```

I want to be able to go through the list and for each member I want to be able to call the MethodX() within the variant class rather than the inherited Method().

The only way I have found to do this is as follows:

```
foreach (var obj in objectList)
{
   if (obj is ObjectVariant1)
   {
      ObjectVariant1 newObj = (ObjectVariant1)obj;
      newObj.Method();
   }

   if (obj is ObjectVariant2)
   {
      ObjectVariant2 newObj = (ObjectVariant2)obj;
      newObj.Method();
   }
}
```

However I would like to be able to add new ObjectVariant classes easily, without having to add extra checks like these. Is there a way to automate the foreach loop without me having to add a new check for each class that I create?

Thanks!

Comment: Myabe you should look into how [`override`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/override) works

Comment: Look for Virtual and Override methods as @Default said

Comment: Please read [ask] and create a [mcve]. There's no need to cast classes of _your_ type `Object` to `ObjectVariantX` to call your base class's `Object.Method()` method. This only won't work if `objectList` is actually of type `List<System.Object>`, because `System.Object` of course _doesn't_ have a method named `Method()`.

Comment: But _why_ do you want to name `Method1()` and `Method2()` like that? Why not simply override `Method()` as @Default says?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change `Object` to interface `IObject` and use it:

```
public interface IObject
{
   void Method();
}

class ObjectVariant1 : IObject
{
   public void Method() 
   {

   }
}

class ObjectVariant2 : IObject
{
   public void Method() 
   {

   }
}
```

And then you could use your `List<IObject> objectList` and call `obj.Method()`
Another way of doing it (using polymorphism in C#) is by using `virtual` -  `override` keywords

Comment: Your Code does not support base class Implementations.

Comment: It is not necessary at all to change the class to an interface.

Comment: This is a solution that OP could use for his problem and it *works*. The fact that it doesn't solve some *other* problems is irrelevant here.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. I've gone down the virtual-override route :)